# how to get value of selected link value from list of links?

Tags: struts2, hyperlink

In my jsp page I have the following code and it can successfully go to the action class once the link was clicked.

My concern is that I need to know in my action class what is the value of the selected link from the list.

```
<s:iterator value="mediaLendingList" >
<tr> 
   <td><s:url action="addMediaLending" var="urlTag" />
   <a href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />" ><s:property /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: im not really sure what is happening why codes is my question was not formatted eventhough i put 4 spaces before i typed it

Comment: What I do to achieve this maybe is not the best solution, but it works. I put a `<s:form>` instead of `<s:url>`, and insert a `<s:hidden>` inside to travel to the `Action` when the form is submitted. You can populate that hidden field with whatever you want, in your case, `#urlTag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<s:param>` tag to put parameters to `<s:url>` tag and `top` keyword to get current element of the  iteration.

```
<s:iterator value="mediaLendingList">
  <tr> 
   <td>
     <s:url action="addMediaLending" var="urlTag">
      <s:param name="variableName" value="top" />
     </s:url> 
     <s:a href="%{urlTag}"><s:property /></s:a>
   </td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```